# How can I add a query string to a route in php?

Tags: php, routes, kohana-3

I am trying to make the default home page route to certain category by default.

in my routes.php file I have re-routed the publish new action to the home page, as I want the post an ad form to be the home page, but I keep encountering errors when trying to add the query string "?category=wanted-ads"

My goal is I'd like it to default to the form options that are part of the
/publish-new.html?category=wanted-ads page.

Apologies for a simple question, I'm new to php and the kohana framework and I'm using the open classifieds script to create a classifieds site.

Thanks in advance.

```
 URL::title(__('publish new'))

Route::set('post_new', URL::title(__('publish new')).'.html')
->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'new',    
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try get the query string params manually ($_GET)? If yes, what is shown?

By a fast reading in Kohana docs I found something that could help you. Instead you to pass desired category via query string, you can to pass via params.

```
Route::set('post_new', '/post_new/category/:<category>', array('category' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'new',
        'action' => 'index',
));
```

To get this param you just do this:

```
// From within a controller:
$this->request->param('category');

// Can be used anywhere:
Request::current()->param('category');
```

This works perfectly in many others frameworks, probably works fine in Kohana too.

Source: https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#examples